# Google Website Translator - Waiting for translation to finish before displaying page

Tags: javascript, html, translation, google-translate

I'm trying to add localization to my site with minimal effort by using Google Website Translator.  There's one really annoying snag I've run into though:  Every time I try to load a (translated) page, it's displayed briefly in English before Google's javascript does its thing and it toggles to a new language.

I've tried setting "display: none" on my entire HTML body until Google's code finishes running, but I couldn't see anywhere convenient to put the javascript to toggle the display back to normal once the translation code is done without modifying the javascript file that Google loads from Google.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Off-topic side note: Google Translate always give weird translations. :P

Comment: Yeah, but is there a better alternative that doesn't involve training a bunch of monkeys to do all the translations manually?

Answer (score 1):

Try Site Translator - http://www.deskshare.com/translation-software.aspx. The full content of your pages is directly on your website so you don't have to worry about the online service being slow or flashing the English text first.